# High Resolution Google and Bing Map Images

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I want a high resolution image with both the **Bing** and **Google Maps**.
I tried a lot and I got the highest resolution be **1440x937** for **Bing** and **1280x1280** with **GMaps**.
In GMaps the highest is 640x640, but when I put scale=2 with it, it gives a image of 1280x1280, and scale value 1&2 are acceptable only.
Is there any way by mean of which I can take image more than this resolution?
Thanks

Comment: Please let me know what's not clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth Pro allows you to export image 4800px wide and it is now Free, more information here:

https://www.google.ca/work/mapsearth/products/earthpro.html

You have to check the usage you want to do with the imagery and see it fits with the Terms of Use.

On other products or platform, there are some limitations that apply both technical and commercial.

Comment: This is possible when I get the key from Google, is that right? Anything for Bing? As Bing is the 1 which has the higher priority in my case :(

Comment: If you want to use Google Earth Pro, you can use GEPFREE as key according to their documentation.
For Bing, the limits are 900px x 834px (width x height) according to the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Comment: It might work but it is not supported, so the official limits are those communicated. Also, I suggest you remove your key from the sample url!

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I was not able to find the Edit button so deleted it :) and thanks for the positive response :)